# How do I get the components side by side using Angular?

Tags: angular

Please, explain this simple thing to the novice.

So I have 3 three components made in Angular:

- App.Component (Which comes automatically)
- Dog.Component
- Cat.Component

The cat and dog components contain one images of these animals.

**Question: How and where do I put the code snippet when I want to get the cat & dog components side by side(not below)?** Index.html/styles.css? or App.Component? or?

As you can see, I may be a little lost with this structure at this point...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper using a div and then apply the styles in CSS that will make the components be side by side.

**Example**

In your App component HTML:

```html
<div class="app-container">
   <dog-component></dog-component>
   <cat-component></cat-component>
</div>
```

App component CSS:

```css
.app-container {
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used bootstrap to display image side by side.

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

    <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <dog-component></dog-component>
    </div>
  
    <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <cat-component></cat-component>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Make sure that right component selector is used in the app component html file